Windows equivalent of specific LINUX compression tool
In LINUX there is this very specific compression utility/tool at /usr/bin/xz.
Now I am on Windows 10 x64 running PHP 8.1 and I have a php library, that in one line of its code call this very specific LINUX file (everything else in that code is compatible with the Windows, except this one line of code) with some specific switches setting its parameters. This is the line:
$x = proc_open("/usr/bin/xz '--format=raw' '--lzma1=lc=3,lp=0,pb=2,dict=128KiB' '-c' '-'", [0 => ["pipe", "r"], 1 => ["pipe", "w"]], $p);

What I am trying to find is some Windows equivalent utility that I could substitute that LINUX one for, that would accept some similiar switches for setting its attributes, wording may be different - it would be no problem, I would just change them accordingly.
I thought, that windows XZ Utils might be just that, but unfortunately, their xz.exe does not accept any switches that would set its attributes as LINUX file does.
Is there some Windows app (or maybe php script even?) that would do lzma1 data compression similiar to LINUX /usr/bin/xz that I could use under Windows?

I just downloaded the Windows binary. Although the --help page doesn't show it, all of the switches you've show have worked, as far as I can tell. When testing this, skip PHP. Start with getting this working on the Windows CLI in general. Once that's working, then switch over to PHP.

Oh, that's interesting find - thank you. But how come it simply does not work in the PHP? Or I say it in another way: could you please post the very exact line you used now with the windows binary, please? + files from which exact folder did you used (in the zip file there are several folders with different versions)? I used the ones for x64.

@ChrisHaas could you also please download the original example script from here https://jan.fecik.sk/files/qr-generator-platieb-pay-by-square-v-php-381.php substitute there that line for your windows version and tell me what is the value of variable $o (line 26)? Cos mine is still EMPTY, yet there should be quite long string of letters and digits, I guess.

@ChrisHaas regarding your accepted answer - now I have this problem: I am trying to create RELATIVE PATH to the xz.exe instead of the ABSOLUTE PATH that would create problems once deployed to the live server. For some reason, it does not work: if I test for existence of the xz.exe with if(file_exists("xz.exe")) it would pass OK, but as soon as I replace your absolute path with $xz = "xz.exe"; or $xz = "xz"; it does not work. Can you advice me how to solve this, please?

First, it is usually best to attach comments of an answer to the answer itself, not your original question, it is confusing for others to read. To your comment, it is vastly easier to debug an absolute path instead of a relative path, and even more so over "no path" which is what just "xy.exe" is. Your opinion of what a relative/no path is is often not what PHP thinks it is. That's why we use thing like __DIR__ and dirname() to build an absolute path, relatively. So will xz.exe live in the same folder as the script, then my code is portable. Will it live relative, try adding in dirname

Just explanation: originally I had this question under your post, BUT I thought something is wrong cos there were no reply for several hrs, then I deleted it and posted it here and voila, you replied. :-) So that's just that, sorry again. My concern is that when the __DIR__ is called from the script on live server if it won't violate some sort of server path restrictions - sorry, I am no professional, so my questions may sound stupid to professionals (I am trying to understand all of this still).

The __DIR__ constant is "The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned." This is guaranteed to work everywhere. If the user account doesn't have permission to access something, absolute vs relative won't fix anything.

What I was asking was if we can't use just ./xz.exe without the full path? Does that .exe requires us to have it as full path?

My best answer is "maybe". When you use ./xz.exe, that is not relative to the current directory (cd), it is relative to the current working directory (cwd). Often/sometimes the cd and cwd are the same, but it is not a guarantee. The version I showed does always build an absolute path relative to the cd however. I would personally just recommend trying to use __DIR__ on your live server to assuage any concerns. This is how pretty much every system I've built and encountered works, too.

OK, Chris, I will try it once the webpage is completely finished on live server hoping all will be just fine as I do not have experience with these kind of things. And just one side note that comes to my mind right now: could there be some problem on live server regarding calling .exe file from the script (everything would be placed side-by-side exactly as in your example - it works now on my testserver nicely, that is the .exe next to the .php)?

Yes, it is absolutely possible that the user account that PHP is running under will not have permission to run the executable. This will need to be resolved using the OS's permission system. But just try it first before diving into this too deep. PHP also has a feature where you can disable core functions in php.ini, and for security/performance reasons, [some hosts disable proc_open and other executable functions. If you get "call to undefined function", that's probably the reason. But once again, just try it.

Here's my version of your code, hopefully the comments add some clarity.
First, I didn't download the file you requested, I used the one from here: https://tukaani.org/xz/old.html#_windows
Second, my version assumes that the PHP script and the xz.exe file live in the same folder. If that's not the case for you, try my version first, then try to figure out how to change the path.
Third, my version was tested on the CLI only, I don't have the ability to run PHP on my Windows machine (except through WSL).
Fourth, this code writes some sample text to stdin and compresses that, and if that is successful it outputs the binary text (which is worthless, but shows it is working). Normally you'd save this to disk or base64 encode or something else.
<?php

// Variable for the current directory
$dir = __DIR__;

// Absolute path to the binary. This code assumes that it is in the
// same folder as this PHP script.
$xz = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'xz';

// Pipes to read/write to
$descriptorspec = [
   0 => ["pipe", "r"],
   1 => ["pipe", "w"],
   2 => ["pipe", "w"],
];

// Open the process. Use the array format so that automatic
// escaping is handled for you.
$process = proc_open(
    [
        $xz,
        '--format=raw',
        '--lzma1=lc=3,lp=0,pb=2,dict=128KiB',
        '-c',
        '-',
    ],
    $descriptorspec,
    $pipes
);

// Make sure the above worked
if(!$process){
    throw new RuntimeException('Could not open proc');
}

// Write some text to the stream to compress. You could also use
// file_get_contents or one of the command line switches
fwrite($pipes[0], 'This is a test');

// We're done writing
fclose($pipes[0]);

// Grab the contents of stdout and stderr
$output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
$error  = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);

fclose($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[2]);

// Clean up
if(!$return_value = proc_close($process)){
    // Successfully ran the command, do something with $output
    echo 'Output:', PHP_EOL, $output;
}else{
    echo 'There was an error, the command returned: ' . $return_value;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo $error;
}

